# Script to add one value to array in mongo collection

Tags: mongodb

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55addc2f8dab32aca87ce0bd"),
    "partNum" : "part1",
    "dest" : "First Part",
    "sales" : [ 
        "sale1", 
        "sale2", 
        "sale3"
    ],
    "salesData" : {
        "sale1" : {
            "mcode" : "mc11",
            "dtype" : [ 
                "AAA", 
                "BBB"
            ]
        }
    }
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55addc408dab32aca87ce0be"),
    "partNum" : "part2",
    "dest" : "Second Part",
    "sales" : [ 
        "sale1", 
        "sale2", 
        "sale3"
    ],
    "salesData" : {
        "sale1" : {
            "mcode" : "mc22",
            "dtype" : [ 
                "AAA", 
                "BBB"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am not that much efficient in writing mongo script. My requirement is to append one more value to "dtype" array wherever "mcode" is "mc11" in all of the documents inside the collection. Above is the two document output from my collection. I was using the below script to do it and its not working. Can anyone please help me

```
db.testingRD.find().forEach( function(myDocument) 
{
    db.testingRD.update({id: myDocument._id}, {$push : {"salesData.sale1.dtype" : "DDD"}});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append one more value to `"dtype"` array wherever `"mcode"` is `"mc11"`, use the following **[update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update)** where the `query` object is the selection criteria for the update and is the same query selector as in the **`find()`** method, the `update` object has the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) modifications to apply and then the `options` document which is optional. If that is set to true, it updates multiple documents that meet the query criteria:

```
var query = { "salesData.sale1.mcode": "mc11" },
    update = {
        "$push": { "salesData.sale1.dtype": "DDD" }
    },
    options = { "multi": true };

db.testingRD.update(query, update, options);
```

Comment: Hi Chridam, sorry I could not reply to this yesterday. your solution was really helpful to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You had a typing mistake in the script (you forgot an underscore):

```
db.testingRD.find().forEach( function(myDocument) 
{
    db.testingRD.update({_id: myDocument._id}, {$push : {"salesData.sale1.dtype" : "DDD"}});
});
```

I always use a trick when an update seams to not working: I change the update with a printjson + find so that I can see if it is matching anything:

```
db.testingRD.find().forEach( function(myDocument) { printjson(db.testingRD.find({_id: myDocument._id})) } );
```